# how to calculate std dev in file

Tags: python, standard-deviation

i have input file like this

```
@a
CTCTCTTTAGAACAATCATCACATACCCCTGGTT
+
1>1A>FDF3113B11BB1BAED1D11BAEE0ABG
@b
CAATGCAGCGAACAATGTTCTGGTGGTTGAATTT
+
111>1@11C?1AE?BFDGGGGGBGCCGGGGHHHH
....
```

i calculated the avg quality scores in this file but need help in calculating the standard
deviation of that score

here what i did

```
import sys,csv
import numpy as np
import math

r = open(sys.argv[1],"r")

length =200
a = np.zeros(length)
b = np.zeros(length)
av = np.zeros(length)

while True:
    id = reads.readline().rstrip()
    if id == "":
       break
    seq= r.readline().rstrip()
    p = r.readline().rstrip()
    qua = r.readline().rstrip()
    l= len(qua)
    q = [ord(character) - 33 for character in qua]
    for i in range(l):
        a[i] += q[i]
        b[i] += 1

for j in range(length):
     av[j] = float(a[j]) / b[j]
     s2 = sum((x - av[j])**2  for x in q[i])/b[j] # error in this
     standard_deviation = s2**0.5
     print standard_deviation
```

Comment: Why are you [reinventing the wheel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)?

Comment: i am just creating empty arrays with numpy zeros method and calculating the avg scores from them!is there any better method @hd1

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import sys,csv
import numpy as np
import math

r = open(sys.argv[1],"r")

while True:
    id = reads.readline().rstrip()
    if id == "":
       break
    seq= r.readline().rstrip()
    p = r.readline().rstrip()
    qua = r.readline().rstrip()
    q = [ord(character) - 33 for character in qua]

    mean = np.mean(q)
    standard_deviation = np.std(q)
```

Comment: i want the standard deviation and mean across the 1,2 in each qua,but not the individual quality @Mark Lakata